# Select data from multiple tables and output results as json

Tags: mysql, database

I wrote this query for getting data from 3 different tables which has one similar column.

The trouble is, it throws an error:

> **500 internal server error**

I need the output to be in the form of json, and the values from the task columns  should be child arrays (in the json).

Please let me know where the error is in this query.

```
 $query2 = "SELECT
                jos_mobile_contacts.contact_record_id,
                jos_mobile_contacts.firstName,
                jos_mobile_contacts.lastName,
                jos_mobile_contacts.mobiePhoneNumber,
                jos_mobile_contacts.officePhoneNumber,
                jos_mobile_contacts.contactType,
                jos_mobile_contacts.email,
                jos_mobile_contacts.address,
                jos_mobile_contacts.address2,
                jos_mobile_contacts.city,
                jos_mobile_contacts.state,
                jos_mobile_contacts.zip,
                jos_mobile_contacts.notes,
                jos_mobile_contacts.customfield1,
                jos_mobile_contacts.customfield2,
                jos_mobile_contacts.customfield3,
                jos_mobile_contacts.companyName,
                jos_mobile_contacts.title,
                jos_tasks.title,
                josi_tasks.priority,
                jos_tasks.description
            FROM jos_mobile_contacts
            INNER JOIN jos_tasks
            WHERE jos_mobile_contacts.registered_mobile_id ='453'
              and jos_tasks.registered_mobile_id ='453'";

$db->setQuery($query2);
$db->query();
$numrows= $db->getNumRows();
$rowsContacts = $db->loadAssocList();

if ($numrows <= 0 ) {
    $displayAction = "display:none";
} else {
    foreach ($rowsContacts as $contactInfo) {
        $row_array['contactsId']= $contactInfo['contact_record_id'];
        $row_array['firstName']= $contactInfo['firstName'];
        $row_array['lastName']= $contactInfo['lastName'];
        $row_array['mobiePhoneNumber']= $contactInfo['mobiePhoneNumber'];
        $row_array['officePhoneNumber']= $contactInfo['officePhoneNumber'];
        $row_array['priority']= $contactInfo['priority'];
        $row_array['title']= $contactInfo['title'];
    }
    echo $row_array;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to take a look into the documentary:
https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: @Manoj your question is Unclear because: 1. We don't have access to your database tables' structure/data 2. You did not offer a specific error -- we need to know what is causing the internal error (you need to turn on error reporting) 3. We don't know the specific json output that you require.   If you can supply us with the above details, I am confident that I can provide a correct and educational answer for you.

Comment: @Manoj Furthermore John Pitchers' answer has design flaws in it that I would like to correct, but not before I get the "full story" from you.

Comment: After editing your question and adding newlines in your SELECT statement to eliminate horizontal scrolling, I've got a pretty fair guess that one of the issues with your query is that you don't have a `josi_tasks` table.  (little typos make all the difference)  Please provide the details that I requested earlier so that I can post a complete answer with supplemental advice.

Answer (score 2):

A 500 error isn't specific enough to know exactly what caused the crash but I see some issues in your code.

1. Firstly, your query only references 2 tables not 3 like you stated in your question so it may be completely wrong.
2. Usually, the table prefix (jos_) would be replaced with #__. This way you can install your code on multiple sites with different database prefixes.
3. $db->query() is deprecated and not necessary. $db->loadAssocList will perform the query anyway.
4. You are using echo to output an array. Use json_encode to encode your array into a json string.

The exact cause of your 500 error could be any of the above, I suspect number 4.

I can't test the below code without access to your database but this should get you on the right track.

```
$mobileid = 453;
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select('contacts.contact_record_id, contacts.firstName, 
    contacts.lastName, contacts.mobiePhoneNumber, 
    contacts.officePhoneNumber, contacts.contactType, 
    contacts.email, contacts.address, contacts.address2, 
    contacts.city, contacts.state, contacts.zip, 
    contacts.notes, contacts.customfield1, contacts.customfield2,  
    contacts.customfield3, contacts.companyName, contacts.title, 
    tasks.title, josi_tasks.priority, tasks.description')
    ->from('#__tasks AS tasks')
    ->innerJoin('#__mobile_contacts AS contacts ON tasks.registered_mobile_id = contacts.registered_mobile_id')
    ->where('tasks.registered_mobile_id = '.$mobileid);

$db->setQuery($query2);
$rowsContacts = $db->loadAssocList();

if (count($rowsContacts)){
    $displayAction = "display:none";
} else {
    foreach ($rowsContacts as $contactInfo) {
        $row_array['contactsId']        = $contactInfo['contact_record_id'];
        $row_array['firstName']         = $contactInfo['firstName'];
        $row_array['lastName']          = $contactInfo['lastName'];
        $row_array['mobiePhoneNumber']  = $contactInfo['mobiePhoneNumber'];
        $row_array['officePhoneNumber'] = $contactInfo['officePhoneNumber'];
        $row_array['priority']          = $contactInfo['priority'];
        $row_array['title']             = $contactInfo['title'];
    }
    $output = json_encode($row_array);
    echo $output;
}
```

I hope this helps.
Regards
John

Comment: thanks for helping me.. 
yes i got that but what is here **$mobileid**

Comment: jos_task or jos_contact thing is working..
how do i get all task of perticular contact